# Setting file access permission

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, file-permissions

I am writing on c# code in which, I want to create one text file, In that file  going to store encrypted data, I don't want to allow any user to open,edit delete that file.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"E:\data.txt",FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Read,FileShare.None);
```

any user should not be able to one that file externally as well just like windows folder files.

Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

The `FileAccess` and `FileShare` enums in the `FileStream` constructor describe the access of other applications to the file being read or written. You can't set the Windows permissions with it.

The method you need for that is [`File.SetAccessControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx). That method is heavily documented, so I would suggest to give it a try.

Small sample:

```
FileSecurity fs = File.GetAccessControl(fileName);

fs.AddAccessRule( new FileSystemAccessRule(account
                , FileSystemRights.ReadData
                , AccessControlType.Deny
                );
```